# Typescript error when creating an array of jsx elements in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that renders an array of texts. I need these texts to have the ability to be **bold**, so instead of plain strings, they are an array of jsx elements.

```
interface ISection {
    title: string;
    body: JSX.Element[];
}
const Section = () => {
    const testSection: ISection = {
        title: 'Test Section',
        body: [
            // Type expected. ts(1110)
            <>
                // Cannot find name 'This'. ts(2304)
                This is a <strong>Test</strong>
            </>
        ]
    }
}
```

Aside from the `ts` errors, a compile error is thrown: `Type parameter list cannot be empty.`

What is confusing is that I've done something like this before, but in a different repository. I'm just porting this feature into a different one. In that other repository, it works just fine, but here throws an error.

Comment: What's the file extension? If you're trying this in a `.ts` file it's not going to work, but it should be ok in a `.tsx` file...

Comment: @gerrod Oh wow! I didn't know there are important distinctions between a `.ts` and `.tsx` files. I thought they were for naming conventions only. Changed the file into a `.tsx` and fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: No worries... I've been bitten by that one before too 